# Refreshing a View in onResume Android

Tags: android, android-view, imagebutton, onresume

How can I refresh my View to update? The reason I want to do this is because I have an `ImageButton` that will only be displayed if a certain condition is true. When the user navigates back to the Activity.

This is the code I have in my `onResume` method but it does not do anything. I thought by calling `setContentView()` again It would just reload the content but because the `ImageButton` is now set to `VISIBLE` it would be shown.

CODE:

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resume Size: " + Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    price.setText(String.valueOf(Order.getInstance().getAmount()));
    confirmOrderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    if(Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size() > 0){
        confirmOrderBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_starters);
        confirmOrderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Load up review order
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "REVIEW ORDER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I find it the best when the task is not to complex! :P

Comment: See my edit, hope it helps. And why are you setting listener twice on the same button. If you need to perform different actions on same button rather go for using some boolean flag.

Comment: I want the button to do 2 different things depending on the screen the user is on. I will look into the flag idea. The above should still work though right?

Comment: First thing, don't call setContentView() again because this will invalidate the previous view and android system will never know which button you are talking about. Again, you have to find all the id of your buttons, text views etc. Sorry for my previous comment, look for my answer.

Comment: As per docs, you should make static setups or create views in onCreate(). In onResume(), your activity comes at the top of stack thus, interatcing with user. For more info check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Using [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) with [loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) might help.

Answer (score 3):

`setVisibility()` on its own should `invalidate()` your View. You should debug and check that your `getOrderItems().size()` call is returning what you expect. You should never call `setContentView()` again after `onCreate()` though.

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure calling `setContentView()` was a bad move. I'll look into what you suggested. If `getOrderItems().size()` is returning the correct values do you see any reason why my code should not work?

Comment: Yeah, calling `setContentView()` again will require you to reinitialize all of your views (such as your buttons).

Comment: I checked and the `getOrderItems().size()` is returning a value > 0 as expected. The view is not refreshing though.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` put this code

```
        confirmOrderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Load up review order
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "REVIEW ORDER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

In your `onResume` use this:

```
if(Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size() > 0){
        confirmOrderBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```